# my browser does not change website according to my CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css, browser

I really don't know what to do.
my browser does not change when I change the CSS

the case is like this :
I have a class called `wraper` in CSS and html, this class is a div wrapping 2 childs divs
I applied `display : none` to this class, so this class shouldn't be visible, but in fact, the div is visible

so I inspect the element, and I found that the div does not have class in browser console, just user agent stylesheet

here is the screenshot :

[image: CSS]

[image: browser console]

`div class='wraper'` only has user agent stylesheet and even though I set the height and width to 900px and 300px, when I inspect the div has 1343px x 0px

the structure of the HTML is like this :

```
<div class='wraper'>
<div class='gambar-testi'></div>
<div class='preview-testi'><h2> Testimoni</h2>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Pellentesque erat ex, dapibus sit 
amet lobortis eget, consequat vel nisi. Aliquam ac 
enim eget libero pretium venenatis id sed nibh.</span></div>
```

and CSS :

```
.wraper {
width : 900px;
height : 300px;
display : none;
}
.gambar-testi {
display : inline-block;
margin : 10px;
background-color : red;
width : 47%;
height : 340px;
}

.preview-testi {
width : 47%;
display : inline-block;
margin : 0 30px;
}
.preview-testi span {
font-size : 30px;
}
```

another problem, I just changed `.gambar-testi` attribute from `float : left` to `display : inline-block` a few moments ago
I inspect the element in browser console and it shows the attribute is still `float : left` not yet changed to `display : inline-block`

[image]

```css
.wraper {
 width : 900px;
 height : 300px;
 display : none
}
.gambar-testi {
 display : inline-block;
 margin : 10px;
 background-color : red;
 width : 47%;
 height : 340px;
}

.preview-testi {
 width : 47%;
 display : inline-block;
 margin : 0 30px;
}
.preview-testi span {
 font-size : 30px;
  color : black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
<div class="wraper">
 <div class="gambar-testi"></div>
 <div class="preview-testi"><h2> Testimoni</h2>
 <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque erat ex, dapibus sit amet lobortis eget, consequat vel nisi. Aliquam ac enim eget libero pretium venenatis id sed nibh.</span>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I also tried Jsfiddle to recreate the problem but the result is not showing here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/xqxkzhfL/

also tried creating it in SO code Snippet but the result is not showing too
please help I already don't know what to do anymore... this is all I know so far

**EDIT**
sorry I was stupid, in jsfiddle and SO code snippet I applied `display : none` to `.wraper` so of course is does not show results because the display is none...
yeah it works in jsfiddle and SO code snippet but **it does not work** in my localhost ..... why?

Comment: Are you using some kind of CMS? Like drupal, wordpress ??

Comment: did you check with your browser catch ?

Comment: no... I just use xampp. notepad++, and does this in localhost

Comment: @JishnuVS how to check browser catch? can you tell me how to do it? it's my first time hearing it

Comment: just press shift + ctrl + delete together and remove your browser catch

Comment: @JishnuVS oh you mean clearing cache?? yes I did that too before posting this question. I already restarted my browser, cleared cached, history, restarted XAMPP, and even my PC

Comment: have you missed any css closing tag ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130994/discussion-between-jishnu-v-s-and-citra45abadi).

Comment: @JishnuVS I copy pasted my html and css into this post, and haven't touched it again so if there's anything I missed here you can point it to me.  but I don't think I missed any closing tag.... I just checked it too

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure your browser won't cached your old web page
In chrome, keep "Developer Console (F12) appeared, and then Settings->Network->Disable cache(while DevTools is open)[image]